# Default quality when video start

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api

i use this code for show youtube player in my website,

```
<iframe width="1920" height="1080" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ID?vq=hd1080&modestbranding=0&autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=1&fs=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&controls=2&autohide=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I use "vq=hd1080" for play video with full-hd quality. But the quality of video when start is 720p. How can change the default quality(1080p) when video start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`player.setPlaybackQuality(suggestedQuality:String):Void`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_quality). This function sets the suggested video quality for the current video.

However, please note that if you set a `suggestedQuality` level that is not available for the video, then the quality will be set to the next lowest level that is available. For example, if you request a quality level of `hd1080`, and that is unavailable, then the playback quality will be set to `hd720`. With this, you may want to first retrieve the actual video quality of the current video using `player.getPlaybackQuality():String`.

And, based from this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/2kNEzGaVnsw), you can only set the quality after the video has started playing.